# Continuity of the canonical map

Tags: general-topology, group-theory

I have canonical map $\phi$, I think that it is continuous, but I can not prove it.

$$\phi:G/G^x\longrightarrow G(x)$$

$G$ is tological group.

$G^x=\{g\in G\mid gx=x\}$ (Isotropy Group).

$G(x)=\{gx\mid g\in G\}$ (Group Orbit).

Comment: I think a good deal of background is missing here: a topological group is (continuously, apparently) acting on itself...how? Then  you have a set map from the set of left(right) cosets $\,G/G^x\,$ to $\,G(x):=\mathcal Orb(x)\,$ and you want to know whether this map is continous...but with what topology on the set $\,G/G^x\,$ ? The quotient one or what?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The map $\theta:G\longmapsto G(x)$ which sends $g$ to $gx$ is continuous and surjective. Also, if $g^{-1}h\in G^x$, then $g^{-1}hx=x$ so $gx=hx$. Hence $\theta$ factors uniquely through a surjective continuous map from $G/G^x$ onto $G(x)$. This is $\Phi$. I assume of course that $G/G^x$ is equipped with the quotient topology, since the former claim is using its universal property.

Comment: @Caloric You're welcome!